# Weird cases when drag and droping files in to vscode terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

**My problem**
I am currently working with Python in VS Code and I encountered a weird problem with the drag and drop feature. When I drag a folder path or a file path into the Terminal, then it always begins with the &
sign. This only happens when I start my program.
Here is an example:
`& 'filepath'` or
`& "filepath"`
I don't have a problem with the quotes but with the `&` and the `blankspace`. I can't find anything online, I was wondering if anybody else has this problem.

Thanks in advance :)

**What did you try and what were you expecting?**
Well, I did try it with other files and folders, but it didn't help.
I've also tried running the code outside VS Code and drag and dropping was fine. So I guess it has something to do with VS Code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens in certain conditions when the path contains a space or parenthesis and the current terminal is powershell based.

I'm not sure why this was added, but the mechanism happens here:

[src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalInstance.ts:2664](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/5807d5f2c741af3f84a9c32ab0ebb11cdc5dfabc/src/vs/workbench/contrib/terminal/browser/terminalInstance.ts#L2664-L2668)

```
    if (isPowerShell && (hasSpace || originalPath.indexOf('\'') !== -1)) {
        return `& '${originalPath.replace(/'/g, '\'\'')}'`;
    }

    if (hasParens && isPowerShell) {
        return `& '${originalPath}'`;
    }
```

The original PRs introducing this change are [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/65331) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/pull/65994)

The rationale seems to be to run files with certain symbols in their name:

> single quotes in paths for PowerShell (i.e /Users/tyler/tyler's stuff/ -> & '/Users/tyler/tyler''s stuff/' to escape a ' in a '  ' string, you add an extra ')

The smallest workaround is to not open a powershell terminal.

So either open a terminal with the drop-down next to the "+" (`@command:workbench.action.terminal.newWithProfile`) which should have other entries next to powershell like "Command Prompt"(cmd.exe).

If you want to make this the default select the terminal profile then use the "Terminal: Select Default Profile"
(`@command:workbench.action.terminal.selectDefaultShell`) command to change the default.

If you want this to be configurable or not happen when the foreground application is no longer powershell you should probably file an issue with vscode.